# Poor image resolution when using imageList in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resolution, picturebox, imagelist

I am using an imageList which has 5 images stored, 3 of which are .jpg and 2 .bmp.

I am using these images to change a picturebox image using a timer -

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imgIndex++];
    }
```

where `private int imgIndex = 0;` is set in the `Form` class.

I have 2 problems, firstly the resolution of the images when displayed in the picture box is very pixelated and of poor quality, and I have tried to resolve this by changing the `ColorDepth` in the `imageList` properties and I have also tried using different image formats i.e. `.gif`, `.png` etc and altering the image size but this does not work. How can I get a better resolution?

The second problem is when the timer gets to the last image, the application crashes with the error 'InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index. Parameter name: index'
There are 5 images in the imageList and when debugging the error arises from `private int imgIndex = 0;` how can I resolve this?

Comment: When there are 5 images, the highest index is 4. The resolution depends on the Size properties much more than on the colordepth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 5 images with 0 index, max index size should be 4 not 5. That's the reason it gives error on value = 5. For resolution, you need to set SizeMode property to Normal

Comment: so do I need to change the private int imgIndex? And if so to what?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN-> "ImageList is typically used by other controls, such as the ListView, TreeView, or ToolBar".  Although you may be able to use ImageList your way you might be seeing some of unintended side effects of using it that way.  Try using a List of images instead of an ImageList.

```
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

// assign images.  images.Add(...

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = images[imgIndex++];
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I have resolved the image quality issue however still have a problem with the form crashing when it reaches the last photo how can I sort this?

Comment: if (imgIndex >= imageList1.Images.Count) imgIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem where every once in a while, the form resource file decides to provide a lower resolution image format for my image list.

I have to **delete the images from the image list and re-add them** to get the full resolution back.